# How To Make Two Password Entry With Validation Both Password Must Be The Same?

Tags: javascript

I want the user to enter 2 password and the the password must match, in order to finish the sign up form. I know that there are several question like this and I have try them all out, but none is working. Please help me with this

I have try some coding from the internet but it did not work.

```
<form method = "POST" action="daftar.php" autocomplete="off">
    <center>
    <table>
    <tr><th>Nama Penuh:</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="namapeminjam" size="24" 
placeholder="Mohamad Ziqreey" minlength="5" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>No KP:</th>
    <td><input type="text" id="id" name="nokppeminjam" size="24" 
minlength="12" maxlength="12" required="" placeholder="Tanpa '-' Atau 
Jarak"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Kata Laluan:</th>
    <td><input type="password" name="katalaluan" size="24" 
placeholder="zIqreey@123" minlength="8" maxlength="16" title="Kata Laluan 
Anda Perlulah Terdiri Dari Lapan Aksara Mengandungi Sekurang-Kurangnya 1 
Huruf Besar Dan Dan Huruf Kecil Termasuk Sekurang-Kurangnya Satu Nombor" 
required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" id="idd"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th>Kata Laluan:</th>
    <td><input type="password" name="katalaluan2" size="24" 
placeholder="zIqreey@123" minlength="8" maxlength="16" title="Kata Laluan 
Anda Perlulah Terdiri Dari Lapan Aksara Mengandungi Sekurang-Kurangnya 1 
Huruf Besar Dan Dan Huruf Kecil Termasuk Sekurang-Kurangnya Satu Nombor" 
required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" id="idd2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Tunjukkan Kata Laluan

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("idd");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
</script>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function validatePasswords()
   {
      var pass1=document.getElementById("katalaluan").value;
      var pass2=document.getElementById("katalaluan2").value;
      if(! pass1==pass2) 
       {
          alert("passwords don't match");
          return false;
       }
      return true;
   }
</script>

<br><br>
    <center><input  id="buttonon" type ="submit" name="daftarpengguna" 
value="DAFTAR" onclick="return validatePasswords();"/>
    </center>
    </form>
```

Comment: `if(pass1 != pass2) `

Comment: Thank You, I do not know it was that simple..haha..thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to find the inputs by their name using the `getElementById` function.  You need to pass in the Id instead to the function.

Second, the `if` statement isn't formatted correctly.  The explanation mark should be next to the equals sign.

```
function validatePasswords()
{
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("idd").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("idd2").value;
    if(pass1 != pass2) 
    {
        alert("passwords don't match");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```